# Maintaining Floating Point Accuracy with a Running Average

Tags: c++, floating-point

I need to calculate the mean-squared error of a 16-bit operation for an arbitrary number of data points (upwards of 100 million).  I decided to go with a running average so I wouldn't have to worry about overflow from adding a large number of squared errors.  At 100 million samples I had problems with floating point precision (inaccurate results) so I moved to double.

Here is my code

```
int iDifference = getIdeal() - getValue();

m_iCycles++;


// calculate the running MSE as

// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

// MSE(i + 1) = MSE(i) + (E^2 - MSE(i))/(i + 1)

m_dMSE = m_dMSE + ((pow((double)iDifference,2) - m_dMSE) / (double)m_iCycles);
```

Is there a better way to implement this to maintain accuracy?  I considered normalizing the MSE to one and simply keeping a sum with a final division on completion to calculate the average.

Comment: As a totally side note, depending on whether you pick up the `pow(double, int)` overload, `iDifference*iDifference` could be orders of magnitude faster than the `pow` call.

Comment: Agreed.  I should have caught that.  Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Floating point numbers don't overflow in this kind of situation, they only lose precision. So there are no advantages of a running average over a running total here. The consequence is the same whether the running total or the denominator grows.

To maintain precision in a running total, keep subtotals instead of a single total. Just keep adding to a subtotal until adding one more would cause overflow. Then move on to the next subtotal. Since they are all the same order of magnitude (in base 2), optimal precision may be achieved by converting to floating point and using a pairwise accumulation into one final total.

```
// first = errors, second = counter
typedef pair< vector< uint32_t >, uint32_t > running_subtotals;

void accumulate_error( uint32_t error, running_subtotals &acc ) {
    ( numeric_limits< uint32_t >::max() - error < acc.first.back()?
        * acc.first.insert( acc.first.end(), 0 ) : acc.first.back() )
        += error; // add error to current subtotal, or new one if needed
    ++ acc.second; // increment counter
}

double get_average_error( running_subtotals const &total ) {
    vector< double > acc( total.first.begin(), total.first.end() );
    while ( acc.size() != 1 ) {
        if ( acc.size() % 2 ) acc.push_back( 0 );
        for ( size_t index = 0; index < acc.size() / 2; ++ index ) {
            acc[ index ] = acc[ index * 2 ] + acc[ index * 2 + 1 ];
        }
        acc.resize( acc.size() / 2 );
    }
    return acc.front() / total.second;
}
```

Comment: "Floating point numbers don't overflow in this kind of situation, they only lose precision." Can't losing precision lead to overflow? A less precise float may be smaller *or* bigger than the real value may it not?

Comment: @JosephGarvin When the most-significant bit of the addend is smaller than the least-significant bit of the total, rounding down is guaranteed. Otherwise, you're right, the point of round-to-nearest is to prevent such bias. (Total elimination of bias requires a linear distribution of numbers, though, and many data sets have exponential or otherwise uneven distribution instead.) A well-designed program should never even come close to overflow (to infinity); I think it'd be a bug to have `INFINITY` within the margin of error.

Answer (score 15):

You might want to look at the [Kahan Summation Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) - it's not *exactly* what you need here but it solves a very similar problem and you may be able to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Very cool, +1. However, that will cease to be effective one the running total is large enough that adding any error to it effectively adds 0. At that point, the error accumulator begins to grow rapidly, until it loses precision as well. Then he's back at square 1.

Comment: +1, Definitely cool.  I tend to agree with Potatoswatter that I'll still loose precision as the number of data points grows.

Answer (score 2):

If your other solutions don't work you might investigate the [Bignum library](http://gmplib.org/)

"GMP is a free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on signed integers, rational numbers, and floating point numbers. There is no practical limit to the precision except the ones implied by the available memory in the machine GMP runs on. GMP has a rich set of functions, and the functions have a regular interface. "

Comment: I like this too.  Ultimately decided I'd rather not add any extra overhead for a single variable.